# Given an bool array, how to make these loops more performant?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

If you have:

```
bool[] arrayExample = {false, true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true};
```

Given an `n` value, I am looping through the array to find which index has a True value.

For example: `if n = 1`: I want to return all index's that have 1 True value. Therefore the return list would be `{1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10}`

`if n = 2`: I want to return list to have the index's where there is 2 True values in a row: `{4, 8, 9}`

Also, I would like to do this for `n=3`?

Is there a cleaner/more performant way to run this code?

```
List<int> indices = new List<int>();
bool counter = false;

if (n == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayExample.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (arrayExample[i])
        {
            indices.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
else if (n == 2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayExample.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (counter == true && arrayExample[i] == false)
        {
            counter = false;
        }
        if (arrayExample [i])
        {
            if (counter == false)
            {
                counter = true;
            }
            else
            {
                indices.Add(i);
                counter = false;
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: What are counter, interval and availabilityArray?

Comment: Is performance a bottleneck here? This looks like spaghetti code that needs to be rewritten for clarity, but unless performance is unacceptable, don't try to micro-optimize.

Comment: Does this code give the correct answer? If so, you should checkout [codereview.se] to get feedback on how you can improve it. This can include how to make your code more understandable and use idiomatic constructs from C# as well as optimizations.

Comment: Can `interval` only be 1 or 2?

Comment: Using linq : int[] results = arrayExample.Select((x, i) => new { x = x, i = i }).Where(x => x.x).Select(x => x.i).ToArray();

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It does give me the right answer. Thank you

Comment: @StriplingWarrior interval can be anything. Thank you

Comment: @OlivierRogier sorry, needed to edit the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of your code is probably okay; however, you can simplify the algorithm

```
const bool F = false, T = true;
bool[] arrayExample = { F, T, F, F, T, T, F, F, T, T, T };

var indices = new List<int>();
int count = 0;
int n = 2;
int delta = n - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < arrayExample.Length; i++) {
    if (arrayExample[i]) {
        count++;
        if (count >= n)
            indices.Add(i - delta);
    } else
        count = 0;
}
```

This works for any `n`. Count how many succeeding `true` values you encountered and add an index whenever this count is a least equal to the required sequence length. Since you want the index of the first index in your sequence, you must subtract `n - 1`.

This algorithm directly yields the indices in ascending order, does not need a temporary array and has no nested loops. I.e., it has a time performance of `O(n)` (here `n` stands for the length of the input).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an idea:
Take your example array: `[F,T,F,F,T,T,F,F,T,T,T]`
Go from end to start, and mark how many True values you have encountered at each position: `[0,1,0,0,2,1,0,0,3,2,1]`.
Now you can get the answer for any n: return every index where `array[index] >= n`

Comment: I really like this approach. I will see if I can program this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   bool[] arrayExample = { false, true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true };
   List<int> result = Foo(1, arrayExample);
   foreach(var num in result)
      Console.WriteLine(num);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
static List<int> Foo(int num,bool[] arr)
{
    List<int> indices = new List<int>();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
       if(arr[i])
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
           {
               if(!arr[i+j])
               {
                     count = 0;
                     break;
               }
                  count++;
           }
                    if (count > 0)
                        indices.Add(i);
       }
   }
  return indices;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured I'd throw my code in the mix (never quick enough to actually provide any useful insights, anyhow):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> TrueIndicesCounter(int counter, List<bool> booleans)
{
    if (counter <= 0) return new List<int>();
    var truths = new List<int>();
    for (var booleanIndex = 0; booleanIndex < booleans.Count; booleanIndex++)
    {
        var boolean = booleans[booleanIndex];
        if (boolean != true) continue;
        if (counter == 1)
        {
            truths.Add(booleanIndex);
            continue;
        }
        var counterIndex = 1;
        var counterSatisfied = false;
        while (counterIndex <= counter)
        {
            var targetBoolean = booleans.ElementAtOrDefault(booleanIndex + counterIndex);
            if (targetBoolean != true) break;
            counterIndex++;
            if (counterIndex != counter) continue;
            counterSatisfied = true;
            break;
        }
        if (counterSatisfied)
            truths.Add(booleanIndex);
    }
    return truths;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the idea given by @Dennis_E like this:

```
int i, j;
int[] rep = new int[arrayExample.Length];
if (rep[arrayExample.Length - 1])
    rep[arrayExample.Length - 1] = 1;
for (i = arrayExample.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    if (arrayExample[i])
        rep[i] = rep[i + 1] + 1;
for (i = 0 ; i < arrayExample.Length; i++)
    if (count == n)
        indices.Add(i);
```